# Sequelize - How to setup foreign key and join on it

Tags: sequelize.js

I have two tables; userPermissions & permissionItems. userPermissions has a permissionItemId as a foreign key, defined as

```
CONSTRAINT `fk_userPermissions_permissionItemId`
  FOREIGN KEY (`permissionItemId`)
  REFERENCES `mydb`.`permissionItems` (`permissionItemId`)
```

Their Sequelize definitions are

```
const PermissionItem = db.define('permissionItems', {
  permissionItemId: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    autoIncrement: true,
    primaryKey: true
  }
});


const UserPermission = db.define('userPermissions', {
  userPermissionsId: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    autoIncrement: true,
    primaryKey: true
  },
  permissionItemId: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    references: 'permissionItems',
    referencesKey: 'permissionItemId'
  }
});
UserPermission.hasOne(PermissionItem);
```

I am then trying to join those two with the and view the results with

```
UserPermission.findAll({
  include: [{
    model: PermissionItem
  }]
}).then(userPermission => {
  console.log('userPermission', userPermission);
});
```

My expectation here is to get a list of all UserPermissions and outer left join PermissionItem on permissionItemId. Instead, I receive the below error

> Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: Unknown column
>   'permissionItem.userPermissionUserPermissionsId' in 'field list'

Have I constructed the query incorrectly? Or the Sequelize definitions?

I have tried flipping these around and including the reverse, and applying the keys backward, in every combination I could think of, all to no avail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up changing UserPermission to the below. Looks like I don't need to define anything special in the Sequelize model for an existing foreign key in the database, just need to list it in the hasOne call

```
UserPermission = db.define('userPermissions', {
  userPermissionsId: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    autoIncrement: true,
    primaryKey: true
  },
  permissionItemId: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER
  }
});
UserPermission.hasMany(PermissionItem, { foreignKey: 'permissionItemId', sourceKey: 'permissionItemId' });
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever I want to make an association I usually defined in both the models and assign alias just to better understand and config properly.

```
    orders.hasMany(models.orderDetails, { 
      as: 'orderDetails',
      foreignKey: 'orderId',
      targetKey: 'id', });

    orderDetails.belongsTo(models.Orders, {
      foreignKey: 'specialOrderId',
      targetKey: 'id',
      as: 'Orders'
    });
```

Whenever you query to create or find:

```
    models.orders.create(ObjectToCreate, {
    include: [{ model: models.orderDeatils, as: 'orderDeatils' }],
  });


    models.orders.findAll({ where: { id: 3}}, {
    include: [{ model: models.orderDeatils, as: 'orderDeatils' }],
  });
```

Comment: you save me ))),I looking fot this answer,for a 2 h

Answer (score 0):

In your `userPermissions` model,
Instead of this

```
UserPermission.hasOne(PermissionItem);
```

try this

```
UserPermission.belongsTo(PermissionItem,{foreignKey:'permissionItemId'});
```

> HasOne and BelongsTo insert the association key in different models
>   from each other. HasOne inserts the association key in target model
>   whereas BelongsTo inserts the association key in the source model.